# Change the iTunes Backup Location in Windows 10 fail

Tags: windows, backup, itunes, links

Cannot create a file when that file already exists? why is this happened?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't make a link if a file or directory of that name already exists.

The syntax is

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    Specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

The first path is the new name (one would normally have a short name for this).  And the second is the existing entity you are linking to.

### EDIT

From that link you have posted, you have missed a step.

> 4. Open File Explorer and navigate to %APPDATA%\Apple
>    Computer\MobileSync\Backup\ (Apple.com version) or
>    %userprofile%\Apple\MobileSync\Backup (Windows 10 Store version).
>    **Delete the backup directory.**

You need to delete the directory first.  Then you can make a link of that name to point to the new backup location.

Comment: https://www.alphr.com/change-itunes-backup-location-windows-10  this is the link i follow and trying to do it's not working.